# Search view with Tab Activity and view pager and fragment a

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, searchview

I have Tabbed activity that includes 6 tab and in the toolbar there is an search view . the problem is when I am click on search view and insert the first letter the selected tabs move to the first tab automatically while I am not selecting that tab. also the search result it comes correct. In my case Example when i am try to  search under Europe Tab the result and selected tab are coming correct but for Example if I swipe the tab to Asia and start insert letters to search the selected tab goes to Europe Tab but the result is coming under Asia Tab. Search Example if i select Asia Tab then insert in search  India the system reset the selection to Europe  but result is correct India is a country under Asia . SEE photos 3 and 4 in 3 selected tab Asia but in photo 4 after insert letter (a) the selected tab automatically switched to Europe . please your help

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: do you use any sort of myTabs.getTabAt(0).select();   ?

Comment: @M.Zain I used that method but nothing is changed

Comment: TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(id);
                tab.select();

Comment: You can try to log message at the place of  TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(id); tab.select(); , and see what happens when you touch the search bar ...